# Command to Download Source Files in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, command, source

In most Linux distros there is a command sometimes the same one used to install or build (compile) packages with extra switch; which just download the source files instead of building or installing them.

I am trying to find the same command in FreeBSD. In FreeBSD we have `portmaster` but I couldn't infer anything like that from its man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`portmaster` ist a simplification for common use cases. For more control you can directly look into the ports collection.

[I assume you already have the ports collection in `/usr/ports`; if see the [handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html) for ways to download it.]

For example `cd /usr/ports/sysutils/lsof` to take a look at the lsof tool. The directory contains a Makefile with all information for this port (where to download it, how to compile it, if/how to apply options). [ports(7)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ports&sektion=7) lists all make targets in a port directory.

A `make fetch` will download the source, `make` will build (extract, patch, and compile) it, `make install` will install it.

Comment: So if I go in each port directory for example `/usr/ports/x11-themes/...` and type `make fetch` all the files mentioned in `Makefile` will be downloaded into `/usr/share/distfiles`?

Comment: Yes. (Even though the list of files may still depend on a port's options, e.g. some can be build with/without plugins.)

Comment: If you run 'make fetch' in the root of the ports tree, it will download all of the files. There are over 30,000 applications, some with many distfiles. This would take a long time and likely not be very useful.